# html form enctype=multipart/form-data

Tags: php, html, web

Hi I'm trying to create a form that will load images following some web examples but I can't get the images to load. I'm working on my personal fedora box running apache. Is there some settings that I have to do differently with Apache?
Here's my form script that should be uploading image:

```
            <form name ="input" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "addPhotograph.php" method = "get">
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <th>Title:</th> <td><input type="text" name ="photoname"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
               <th>Photograph:</th> <td><input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept="image/*"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
               <th>Photographer:</th><td><input type="" name="photographer"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
               <th>Genre:</th><td><input type = "" name="genre"></td>
               </tr>
            <table>   
               <input type="submit" value = "Submit">
            </form>
```

And Here's my PHP script:

```
        <?php
        $uploaddir = '/var/www/html/photodb';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

        echo '<pre>';
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['name'], $uploadfile)) {
            echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        } else {
            echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
        }

        echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
        print_r($_FILES);

        print "</pre>";
        ?>
```

When I add an image through the form the php form fails saying "Possible file upload attack!"
I guess this means either the file was not able to be moved or the file was not uploaded?

I'm doing this for my college assignment any response or other idea is dearly appreciated :).

Comment: try `$uploaddir = '/var/www/html/photodb/';` though you need more security, nothing stopping uploading php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your method to POST:

```
<form name ="input" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "addPhotograph.php" method = "post">
```

You cannot post your files via GET method.

Comment: I thought my method does pay post.

Comment: Just change it to POST and it should works if your path is defined correctly (and writeable)

Comment: Thanks! It is definietly doing something now. I get the following message when I try and upload: Possible file upload attack!
Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Biner-Wallpaper.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpDhnhmZ
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 369791
        )

)

Comment: Not that I get the message above, I believe I need to fix permissions?

Comment: Use if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))

Comment: I did, getting the same error # 6 for some reason. I Google'd and found that this means that temporary file is missing.

Comment: Change $uploaddir = '/var/www/html/photodb'; to $uploaddir = 'var/www/html/photodb/';

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use form post?

```
<form name ="input" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "addPhotograph.php" method = "post">
```